# Nine-Patch Not Working In IntelliJ

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea

I have an Nine-Patch image that is being used in my app. When I build the app with Maven, the images work fine. When I build with IntelliJ Idea 13, the images are treated as a normal PNG (showing the black border) [image: Screenshot].

I've verified that Idea is using the same Android SDK and Java JDK as Maven. I've tried using a known, good Nine Patch image and see the same behavior. The issue seems specific to IntelliJ, builds produced by the build server have no problem.

I'm trying to use this image [image: SampNine Patch] with this code

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/shareButton"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:background="@drawable/bt_classic"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Share This"
    android:textColor="@color/color_white" 
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
```

Comment: Please up-vote this IDEA bug.  We are experiencing the same issue. http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-123428

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a bug in IntelliJ which was reported in http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-120474 and fixed in 13.1.3.